# Is there a supported way to get list of features used by a H2O model during its training?

Tags: h2o

This is my situation.  I have over 400 features, many of which are probably useless and often zero.  I would like to be able to:

- train an model with a subset of those features
- query that model for the features actually used to build that model
- build a H2OFrame containing just those features (I get a sparse list of non-zero values for each row I want to predict.)
- pass this newly constructed frame to H2OModel.predict() to get a prediction

I am pretty sure what found is unsupported but works for now (v 3.13.0.341).  Is there a more robust/supported way of doing this?

```
model._model_json['output']['names']
```

The response variable appears to be the last item in this list.

In a similar vein, it would be nice to have a supported way of finding out which **H2O version** that the model was built under.  I cannot find the version number in the json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know which feature columns the model used after you have built a model you can do the following in python:

```
my_training_frame = your_model.actual_params['training_frame']
```

which will return some frame id

and then you can do

```
col_used = h2o.get_frame(my_training_frame)
col_used
```

**EDITED** (after comment was posted)

To get the columns use:
`col_used.columns`

Also, a quick way to check the version of a saved binary model is to try and load it into h2o, if it loads it is the same version of h2o, if it isn't you will get a warning.

you can also open the saved model file, the first line will list the version of H2O used to create it.

For a model saved as a mojo you can look at the `model.ini` file. It will list the version of H2O.

Comment: col_used.col_names  is the final step I was looking for.  Thanks!
h2o.init doesn't tell me the version the model was built with.  That's what I was looking for.

Comment: After loading my trained model and using the code above, I'm getting "TypeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Comment: hi @Ege can you create a separate stackoverflow question with reproducible code, that will make it easier for folks to debug your issue. thanks!

Comment: Accessing `training_frame` won't work if it was removed after training, if the h2o instance was restarted, or the model has been archived and re-imported (stored on disk, in a code repo, data lake connected to MLflow, etc).